# Safari only displays right half of full-screen div

Tags: html, css

This is one that absolutely confounds me.  I have a site that uses a full-screen "splash screen", which the user then slides away to reveal the content beneath.  In Chrome and Firefox, everything displays properly, but on Safari (both mobile and desktop), the div is split down the middle, the left half of the div is transparent (showing through to the content beneath) and only the right half is visible.  All the content within it is still positioned as if it were full-screen, but it's all abruptly cut off halfway cross the screen, right down the middle of an image and a block of text.  After several days rifling through the inspector I can't find any reason why Safari would be exhibiting this truly bizarre behavior—the split doesn't seem to follow any existing borders or boundaries of any elements, the inspector is acting as if the entire div is visible.

The only thing I can think of is: This issue seems to have appeared around the same time as I introduced some schmancy transform3d effects on the body, is Safari known for being unable to properly handle transform3d effects?

Since I have no idea which section of code could be causing this glitch, I'm not sure what code I would paste here, but the website is http://vanderstank.church.  I apologize again for the broadness of this question, but I am unable to narrow it down any further.  Thanks for any light you may be able to shed on this situation.

Comment: It looks like safari has a bug with `transform: rotatey` when I remove this style from the ones applied to `<div id="front">` on your page, the page works. So, I guess the question is, how important is that transform effect to your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself - it *was* related to the 3D rotation I added.  Turns out I had applied the `rotateY(6deg)` effect not only to `body` but also to the `#front` div.  I couldn't get that `#front` rotation to actually work right, so I'd given up on it... but forgotten to delete the line.

But because `#front` had a `rotateY(6deg)` on it while on the same plane/axis as `body`, it rendered as if the right half of it was "in front of" the body but the left half was "behind" the body.  Still not sure why this only happened in Safari.

Remember to delete or comment out old code, guys!